# Is it possible to put an Azure security group, in front of the MS A. Web Application Firewall (WAF)?

Tags: azure

Microsoft Azure has a web application firewall.  Can I put an Azure security group, in front of, the web application firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

For example, Azure Application Gateway offering a WAF always deployed a virtual network subnet that supports network security groups. You could read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#is-application-gateway-always-deployed-in-a-virtual-network). So you can use an NSG to completely lock down network access to the subnet that contains an Azure Web Application Gateway (WAG)/Web Application Firewall (WAF). You could get more details from [this blog](http://aidanfinn.azurewebsites.net/?p=21474).